# Netbeans 12 en español... ¿cómo se logra?

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu, localización, netbeans-12

Muy buenos dias, nuevo en netbeans 12 y ubuntu 20.04 (java es versión 11)

No encuentro info...

1er intento) Agregar '' en netbeans_options del archivo netbeans.conf (con el tema snap llevó su tiempo..pero quedó bien grabado)

2do intento) agregar --LOCALE es:AR en la línea de ejecución del netbeans.

En ambos casos... sigue en inglés.

¿alguna idea?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Desafortunadamente ya no se puede de esa manera, tiene unas cuantas versiones que eliminaron las traducciones a español. Te suigero levantar un issue en su tracker de l proyecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Usaré la versiónen inglès. 

Abrazo